# Develop Live Connect app without redirect domain

Tags: api, google-chrome, redirect, live, onedrive

I am developing a Chrome extension that needs to use Microsoft's Live Connect API to access Skydrive. The problem is that it requires a redirect domain when registering apps, but I don't have any redirect domain, so does that mean I cannot use the Live Connect API? Or is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should select the option " Mobile client app".